# Python Jupyter Notebook pygame Image: FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, image, pygame, jupyter-notebook

I just started programming. I watched a you tube tutorial on how to create a hangman game with pygame.
When it comes to loading images I get this:

```
***FileNotFoundError**
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-03373876a9dc> in <module>
     29 images = []
     30 for i in range(7):
---> 31     image = pygame.image.load("hangman" + str(i) + ".png")
     32     images.append(image)
     33 
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.*
```

The images (hangman 1...7)are located in the same folder as the ipynb
for example the first one
*(C:\Users\basti\Documents\hangman\hangman1.png)*

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

`range(7)` gives you an iterator from 0 to 6. If your images start at 1 and end at 7, you should use `range(1,8)`

Comment: thanks for your help,  yes forgot this, but unfortunately after correcting the code the same error appears again

Comment: Could you try printing 
`os.path.exists("hangman" + str(i) + ".png")`
before the load, just to see, if python can see the path....

Comment: it says "false". What does it mean that  python can't see the path, I am confused? :D By the way thank you so much :)

Comment: Try using absolute path or perhaps building a path using os.path.join

Comment: Probably the working directory of your jupyter notebook is set to somewhere  weird. You can check it with `%pwd` and change it with `%cd` Try using the absolute path like this: `os.path.join("C:\Users\basti\Documents\hangman\",  "hangman" + str(i) + ".png")`